# How can i make branches or something in Git

Tags: git, version-control

I don't know exactly what is the term for that but i will tell you what i want.

Suppose i am writing the website and i have uploaded the most basic code on the bitbucket.

Now i am going to make continuous changes in the code but i want to separate the repository into sections so that i can clone  any version.

Like suppose i can make the branch 1 as `Sample App without database` then after one months of commit, I want to have another branch called Sample app with database added and son on.

So that i can always clone any of those branches. new branches will have some new files , codes images etc.

Comment: Please clarify this question – that is a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you're looking for **[tags](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging)**.

You can apply a tag to a commit to be able to find it more easily later. It's generally used to mark releases, among other things. The current revision is tagged with the tag `v1.2.3` like this:

```
git tag v1.2.3
```

You can also apply tags to old revisions like this:

```
git tag v1.2.3 9fceb02
```

where `9fceb02` is the checksum/revision of the commit. Tags must be pushed with an explicit command:

```
git push origin --tags
```

Later, you can checkout the tag in your workspace like this:

```
git checkout v1.2.3
```

Comment: if i want clone a particular tag , how can do that in some directory

Comment: The generally used work flow is to checkout the tag in your working directory. I'll add information to my answer.

Comment: You means it is equivalent to `git clone  git@bitbucket.org:user/sample.git` because i am talking about copying in entire new folder brand new computer

Comment: No, it's not equivalent to clone, but if your tags are in a shared repo you can clone the same repo to another computer and there check out the desired tag, as described above.

Comment: ok. i was looking for something like `git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/sample.v1.2.3.git`. is it possible . or have to first clone the whole repo and then checkout the tag. whats the point if i have 100 more files added after that tag and i don't want them. do i still have to download them even though i don't need them

Comment: No, that's not possible unless you create new repos. Cloning is cheap and only done once, so that shouldn't be a huge problem.

Comment: @user33: Please read some git tutorials. From this and you other question I gather that you are severely misunderstanding/abusing git.